# Change Selected tab of jQuery UI tabs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

The question has been asked a few times before, but none of them are similar to my scenario.

I have jQuery Tabs control that loads my tabs via ajax:

```
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
    <% if (AccessControll.HasAccess(Url.Action("ViewSchemeInformation","Scheme"))){%>
        <li><a id="tab_1" href="<%= Url.Action("ViewSchemeInformation","Scheme", new {schemeNumber = Model.SchemeNumber}) %>">Information</a></li>
    <%}%>
    <% if (AccessControll.HasAccess(Url.Action("SchemeUpdate", "Scheme"))){%>
        <li><a id="tab_2" href="<%= Url.Action("SchemeUpdate","Scheme", new {schemeNumber = Model.SchemeNumber}) %>">Update</a></li>
    <%}%>
    <%if (AccessControll.HasAccess(Url.Action("MinimumRequirements","Scheme"))){%>
        <li><a id="tab_3" href="<%= Url.Action("MinimumRequirements","Scheme", new {schemeNumber = Model.SchemeNumber}) %>">Minimum Requirements</a></li>
    <%}%>
</ul>
```

These tabs are shown based on access, so my tab index's are never the same, hence I have added an `id` to each `href`.

I link to this specific page from various places and each link must go to this page and select the tab it refers to.

My url will look something like this: `http://localhost:34412/Scheme/ViewSchemeDetails/BS-000469800000?activeTab=1`

How can I select the tab using jQuery based on the activeTab parameter in my querystring?

Note that number in the querystring always corresponds to the id of my `href`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Get the query string:

```
var queryString = window.location.search;
```

Get the `activeTab` part:

```
var activeTab = queryString.match(/\bactiveTab=([^&]*)/)[1];
```

Select the tab with the right ID:

```
$('#tab_' + activeTab).click();
```

Comment: just to let you know, there there some ie7 issues with the `$('#tab_' + activeTab).click();`

Answer (score 2):

```
tabs_object.tabs('widget').tabs("option", 'selected', 2);
```

in your case

```
tabs_object.tabs('widget').tabs("option", 'selected', activeTab);
```

Comment: This may be for an older version of the tabs widget. "active" (rather than "selected") is what currently works.